# Stream is closing in twitter4j (Hadoop- flume)

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter

I have just installed apache hadoop and expermenting with it. I'm in the first stage, which is extracting data. I'm using the twitter example from cloudera + their VM.

The problem that I have is that the stream which is reading twitter data seems to have issues, I don't know what.

This is my flume.conf:

```
TwitterAgent.sources= Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels= MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks=HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels=MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey=XXX
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret=XXX
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken=XXX
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret= XXX

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords= trump

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/tweets
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=600
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=100
```

Then I start the flume agent using this command:

```
flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f flume.conf
```

Seems very straight forward, but I keep getting this error message when I run the agent:

```
16/10/23 12:41:27 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Starting twitter source org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource{name:Twitter,state:IDLE} ...
16/10/23 12:41:27 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Twitter source Twitter started.
16/10/23 12:41:27 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing connection.
16/10/23 12:41:28 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Connection established.
16/10/23 12:41:28 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Receiving status stream.
16/10/23 12:41:28 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Stream closed.
16/10/23 12:41:28 ERROR twitter.TwitterSource: Exception while streaming tweets
Stream closed.
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=a8fd061d or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=00070a0c
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[a8fd061d-00070a0c a8fd061d-0007099a], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase.handleNextElement(StatusStreamBase.java:199)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamImpl.next(StatusStreamImpl.java:57)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:478)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase.handleNextElement(StatusStreamBase.java:85)
    ... 2 more
```

As you can see, it is at least being able to connect to the twitter API. What is this caused by? Anyone ever experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twitter streaming API has been experiencing problems since the attack on DYN the 21st of October. These have been reported on the twitter developer forum, and twitter staff are aware of the issue: https://twittercommunity.com/t/issues-reported-with-streams-since-10-21/76429.

As of yet, there is not a clear answer for what the cause of the problem is, but the observed behaviour is that connections to any of Twitter's streaming endpoints get closed after short periods of time, normally (although not always) without receiving any data. Sometimes the connection gets closed whilst sending the response resulting in invalid JSON.

Rest endpoints however seem to be working.